# 500 Internal Server Error:System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: settlementlocationcode

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Here I'm trying to bind the data from database to table for selected features within the user entered buffer distance. This is working for simple query, but it doesn't work for query using PostGIS function it shows the error:

> likeSystem.InvalidOperationException: 
>   Missing parameter: settlementlocationcode`

```js
 function Gettable(settlementlocationcode, bufferdistance)
    { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "drop.asmx/GetSchoolData",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",

            data: "{'settlementlocationcode':" + settlementlocationcode + ",'bufferdistance':" + bufferdistance + "}",
            success: function (data) {
                //alert("success");
                $('#dt').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    // 'paging': true,                       
                    // 'scrollY': 200,
                    columns: [                    
                       { 'data': 'districtcode' },
                       { 'data': 'talukcode'},
                       { 'data':'schoolcode' },
                       { 'data': 'schoolname' },
                        { 'data': 'longitude' },
                       { 'data': 'latitude' },                          
                    ]
                });    
            }        
        });    
    }
```